# Add rule to SourceCookifier plugin for notepad++

Tags: css, regex, notepad++

I am trying to add a rule in SourceCookifier for CSS language.

Currently it shows the tree list of

- classes
- Selectors
- Identities

But I want to add my own rule,

I will add some comments, like:

```
/* Start Reset */
-- css rules here
/* End Reset */

/* Start Sidebar */
-- css rules here
/* End Sidebar */
```

And now I want show my own function tree called `section`

Thanks fro help

[image: Source code]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not confident that I understand your question, but here is what I believe you're looking for.

Bring up the language settings for CSS and add a new tag type.  Set the description to "section" (or whatever you like).

For Input, use:
/* Start (\w+)

For Output, use:
\1

If you apply this rule to a file that contains the sample code you provided, this will create sections called "Reset" and "Sidebar."  Is that the effect you're trying to achieve?